# getting "input value must be specified" error while sending graphQL query through java

Tags: graphql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2YQT.jpg)I am trying to get some data by using graphQL. code should be in following format ,but while debugging ,i got error as following:

> [{"message":"\"input\" value must be
>   specified","category":"graphql-input","locations":[{"line":1,"column":10}]}]

Bascially I want data in following format in java .

query  {
      customer {
        id
        addresses {
        id
          firstname
          lastname
          street
          city
          region {
            region_code
            region
            region_id
          }
          postcode
          country_id
          telephone
        }
      }
    }

query i wrote in java is asfollowing :

```
return q -> q.customerId()
            .id()   
            .firstname()
            .lastname()
            .street()
            .city()
            .region(getCustomerAddressRegionQuery())
            .postcode()
            .countryId()
            .telephone();
```

so what java query should i write in order to get the output.
attached image of error here as well

Comment: i updated the format in main question which is working in postman ,according to that what java query do i need to write .all functions are as per above java code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in returning the value from java, the problem is with the graphql query you are performing. The query expects an input named 'input' but you are not giving it. What does your GraphQL query look like?

Comment: i updated the format in main question which is working in postman ,according to that what java query do i need to write .all functions are as per above java code

Comment: it is NOT a java erorr. the query fired in postman is wrong. It needs an input.